# Replace text in java?

Tags: java

wondering if anybody could help me with a query i have? Is there anyway in java for me to create a promt to the user that would allow them to change the options in the displayOptions method? Basically what im trying to do is change exit to finish, if that makes sense?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class part3 {


        private static void displayOptions() {
            System.out.println("Choose your option:");
            System.out.println("**** West End Theatre Booking System ****");
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        System.out.println("1. List all shows and availability");
        System.out.println("2. Book and print ticket(s)");
        System.out.println("3. Cancel a ticket");
        System.out.println("4. Display theatre/show seating map");
        System.out.println("5. Show income/accounts");
        System.out.println("6. Assign new show to theatre");
        System.out.println("7. Exit");
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------


    private static int getUserOption(String prompt) {
        int option;
        Scanner k=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(prompt);
        option=k.nextInt();
        return option;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int selection,wick,oli,phant,wickremain,oliremain,phantremain;
        selection=0;        
        wickremain=24;      wick=0;
        oliremain=40;       oli=0;
        phantremain=32;     phant=0;

        do {

        displayOptions();
        selection=getUserOption("Option? (1-7): ");

        System.out.println();

        if(selection==1){ 


        System.out.println("Wicked (Apollo)");
        if  ( wick>=24){
        System.out.println("Sold Out");
    }   else {      
        System.out.println(wick +" ticket(s) Sold, "+ wickremain+ " ticketAvailable");
    }


        System.out.println("Oliver! (Drury Lane)");
        if  ( oli>=40){
        System.out.println("Sold Out");
    }   else {      
        System.out.println(oli +" ticket(s) Sold, "+ oliremain +" tickets      Available");
    }


        System.out.println("Phantom of the Opera (Her Majesty's)");
        if  ( phant>=32){
        System.out.println("Sold Out");
    }   else {      
        System.out.println(phant +" ticket(s) Sold, " +phantremain+ " tickets Available");
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save all of the options as an array of strings than you can ask the user to input which index position they would like to alter. So:

```
String[] menuOptions = { option1, option2, etc.};
for(int i = 0; i < menuOptions.length - 1; i++)
    System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + menuOptions[i]);

System.out.println("What option would you like to change?");

int temp = k.nextInt();

System.out.println("What would you like that option to become?");

menuOptions[temp-1] = k.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I understood your question, this is how I would solve it:

Just add a check to the `displayOptions()` method.

First you must add a field to the class for knowing if you want to show Finish.

```
public class part3 {
    private static boolean showFinish = false;
```

Then add an `if` clause to the method:

```
if (showFinish) {
    System.out.println("7. Finish");
} else {
    System.out.println("7. Exit");
}
```

Lastly, when you want to change to Finish put this before the call to `displayOptions()`:

```
showFinish = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont reinvent prompt in Java, use available tools, for example:

http://jline.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/jline/jline2

For parsing args

[args4j - Java command line arguments parser](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/)

[Commons Cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Color output on console

[JAnsi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Make it a variable?

```
String optionSeven = "blah";
```

then update optionSeven else where depending on a condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selection statement

```
String exit = "Exit";
String finish = "Finish";
String doh = "DOHH!";

if (someCondition){
    System.out.println("7: " + exit);
} else if (someOtherCondition){
    System.out.println("7: " + finish);
} else {
    System.out.println("7: " + doh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you would like to be able to dynamically change the text of the menu options at runtime. I believe your best bet would be to use a list or some other container for your menu items, and call a method to change the text of a given item. For example, you might have a member variable called options:

`private List<String> options = getDefaultOptions();`

And you could have a method to generate the default options:

```
public List<String> getDefaultOptions() {
    List<String> defaultOptions = new ArrayList<>();
    defaultOptions.add("List all shows and availability");
    defaultOptions.add("Book and print ticket(s)");
    defaultOptions.add("Cancel a ticket");
    defaultOptions.add("Display theatre/show seating map");
    defaultOptions.add("Show income/accounts");
    defaultOptions.add("Assign new show to theatre");
    defaultOptions.add("Exit");
    return defaultOptions;
}
```

Your displayOptions() method would then become:

```
public void displayOptions() {
    System.out.println("Choose your option:");
    System.out.println("**** West End Theatre Booking System ****");
    System.out.println("=========================================");

    int optionNumber = 0;
    for (String option : options) {
        System.out.println(++optionNumber + ". " + option);
    }
}
```

Then, at some point, you could prompt the user to change the text of a particular option, and call this method, with their inputted text:

```
public void changeOptionText(int optionNumber, String newText) {
    options.set(optionNumber-1, newText);
}

...

// Used like this
changeOptionText(7, "finish");
```

Of course you'll want to do some bounds checking and cover some other cases, but this should get you started.